# Why are Vue and my DOM Textarea not in sync (not a reactivity problem)?

Tags: vue.js

I have this weird seemingly reactivity related bug, but it's not reactivity related as far as I can tell.

I'm using a render function to render a textarea.

```
console.log('The value...', self.value);
return createElement("textarea", {
  ...commonAttributes,
}, (self.value));
```

This works up to all the way into the inspector dom. For example, when I set the binding value of the textarea to "abc", the console(self.value) will successfully show "abc", **and even the inspector will show "abc" as innertext**

```
<textarea data-v-c477da9c="" class="TextInput TextInput--multiline TextInput--full-width" data-v-513a62da="">abc</textarea>
```

However, the "visible" text area is still at the last "user inputted" value. When I start typing the inner value is reset to what is seen in the visible DOM element.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner text of a `<textarea>` element designates the default value only; modifying it won't update the textarea's value. When Vue patches the DOM after a re-render it'll reuse the existing textarea element and change its inner text, since that's what you're changing.

You need to set the textarea's value through the `value` prop and handle the `input` event to update the component's data.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    text: 'Hello',
  },
  render(h) {
    return h('div', [
      h('pre', [this.text]),
      h('textarea', {
        domProps: {
          value: this.text
        },
        on: {
          input: e => this.text = e.target.value
        }
      })
    ])
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```